# Is there any standard way to make our own BLE accessory device auto re-connectable in iOS /Android?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I'm wondering whether or not we can make a specific BLE peripheral device with having this ability to be supported by iOS/Android for automatic scanning for automatic reconnecting, i.e without using any extra app.

I think some standard BLE accessory devices (like Heart sensor) are already known by smartphones, so after first-time pairing, the smartphone's OS itself will scan for finding them again automatically for re-connecting each time when the connection gets lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the device is a HID device then the system will auto connect to the device until you disable it in Android and unpair it in iOS.

But what's the purpose if you don't have an app?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I want to ask OS (Android/iOS) to handle the connection part, scanning and auto-connecting, and then inside the app just open a handle to it.

Comment: Do you think we can then ask OS to give access to the connected device?